# Xgboost installation issue on windows on python

Tags: python, installation, pip, xgboost

I am trying to install the Xgboost library.
The problem is that I am on a virtual machine behind a firewall i don't have access to (company computer). I have the Xgboost library that I downloaded from github.

Then I tried to add the path manually to through the Pycharm project interpreter, therefor i don't have any import error detected, the auto completion is even working but when I try to run the code I have this error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/UT2BUP/PycharmProjects/AccountingAdjustment/Run/Execution.py", line 1, in 
>       from Run.Main import Main
>     File "C:\Users\UT2BUP\PycharmProjects\AccountingAdjustment\Run\Main.py", line 22, in 
>       import Modeling.SkLearnHelper as Sk
>     File "C:\Users\UT2BUP\PycharmProjects\AccountingAdjustment\Modeling\SkLearnHelper.py", line 35, in 
>       import Modeling.Stacking as Stk
>     File "C:\Users\UT2BUP\PycharmProjects\AccountingAdjustment\Modeling\Stacking.py", line 6, in 
>       import xgboost as xg
>     File "C:\Users\UT2BUP\Downloads\xgboost-master\python-package\xgboost__init__.py", line 11, in 
>       from .core import DMatrix, Booster
>     File "C:\Users\UT2BUP\Downloads\xgboost-master\python-package\xgboost\core.py", line 112, in 
>       _LIB = _load_lib()
>     File "C:\Users\UT2BUP\Downloads\xgboost-master\python-package\xgboost\core.py", line 103, in _load_lib
>       lib_path = find_lib_path()
>     File "C:\Users\UT2BUP\Downloads\xgboost-master\python-package\xgboost\libpath.py", line 46, in find_lib_path
>       'List of candidates:\n' + ('\n'.join(dll_path)))
>
> xgboost.libpath.XGBoostLibraryNotFound: Cannot find XGBoost Library in the candidate path, did you install compilers and run build.sh in root path?
>   List of candidates:
>   C:\Users\UT2BUP\Downloads\xgboost-master\python-package\xgboost\libxgboost.dll
>   C:\Users\UT2BUP\Downloads\xgboost-master\python-package\xgboost../../lib/libxgboost.dll
>   C:\Users\UT2BUP\Downloads\xgboost-master\python-package\xgboost./lib/libxgboost.dll
>   C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\xgboost\libxgboost.dll
>   C:\Users\UT2BUP\Downloads\xgboost-master\python-package\xgboost../../windows/x64/Release/libxgboost.dll
>   C:\Users\UT2BUP\Downloads\xgboost-master\python-package\xgboost./windows/x64/Release/libxgboost.dll

So I tried to install with PIP in local but when I do

```
python pip install C:\Users\UT2BUP\Downloads\xgboost-master\python-package
```

I got the same error as above (2nd part only).
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most straightforward way is to download the [xgboost wheel](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#xgboost) and install using pip.

```
pip install xgboost‑0.6‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
```

The other option is what you are trying to do now. To build from source, you have to make sure your compiler is set up. For instructions on that, I suggest you start on the [Windows Compilers](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers) page, then visit the docs for [compiling xgboost](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html).

Comment: by doing this i can then just call the xgboost as a classical import ?

Comment: Thanks it works ! just a little add-on, I saw that xgboost is using the depreciated version of the cross-validation function, any way to change that ?

Comment: The version on Christoph's site is 0.6. This is also the latest on PyPI, and is the latest release on the GitHub. So you will see the same message any of the 3 ways.